# Why in MS-SQL-SERVER documentation BETWEEN has lower precedence than AND?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) shows that the AND operator has higher precedence than ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, and SOME.

How can the AND operator, that is used to combine conditions,have higher precedence than operators such as IN, BETWEEN, and LIKE that are used within conditions? It seems impossible to combine conditions before the conditions have been evaluated individually.

What would that mean?

Comment: "Evaluated before" is poor wording for what is actually happening, which is constructing a parse tree, which happens well before actual evaluation takes place.

Comment: @Dai You are wrong.  For Oracle, in  [21c doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/sql-language-reference.pdf) at page 251 (chapert 6-3) you can see that AND has lower precedence than BETWEEN

Comment: Arguably it simply doesn't make sense to discuss precedence within the syntax of a single operator, so the `AND` of `BETWEEN` is irrelevant here, and the "precedence" doesn't actually exist. The documentation simply isn't accurate in that respect, `BETWEEN` and `IN` shouldn't be in the list at all

Comment: Operator Precedence is just about where the implied parentheses would go. e.g. `WHERE cond1 and not cond2 or cond3` is `WHERE (cond1 and (not cond2)) or cond3`

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok I got it.  So tell me if I get this straight: "the Operator Precedence is just about where the implied parentheses would go" means that operator precedence 
(plus explicit use of parentheses) specifies the _semantic_ of conditions in `WHERE` clause but then the Dbms Optimizer is free to process the conditions in whatever order
 it considers more efficent according to the _declarative_ nature of SQL where you specify _what_ you want rather than _how_
 : it is up to the optimizer to choose the most efficient way to produce the desired result.

Comment: No, since these are logical operators there's no difference between "semantics" and "what the optimizer is allowed to do due to the declarative nature of SQL". Think instead in terms of how you could write code with shifted parentheses that somehow fails. Start with, say, `where a between b and c or d = e`. Now try to mess it up: `where a between b and (c or d = e)`. Syntax error, because `c` is not a boolean result (even if it is a bit datatype). The `and` that syntactically follows `between` is part of the `between` and not separate logical operator.

Comment: @allmhuran  
Suppose I have the following table `Test[col1, col2, col3]-->(1,2,'a'),(0,4,'e'),(0,2,'f');`.  If I execute this query `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE col3 LIKE 'a%' AND col1*col1*col1<>0 AND col2/col1>0;` the operator precedence doesn't determine the evaluation order of conditions, but it  is just about where the implied parentheses would go. In this case the two AND have the same precedence and the optimizer is free to execute `(col3 LIKE 'a%' AND col1*col1*col1<>0) AND col2/col1>0` or `col3 LIKE 'a%' AND (col1*col1*col1<>0 AND col2/col1>0) `

Comment: More than the optimizer is free to execute is better to say that the query is parsed in one of that two ways (in my case the first one)  and then the optimizer (always in my case) choose to execute the division col2/col1>0 first  and a `division by zero` error is thrown

Comment: Thanks, good clarification separating parsing from execution. According to the ANSI standard, the order of execution does not have to follow the left to right order of the text. But as mentioned in other comments, the "evaluation" in the documentation is really with respect to parsing, not execution, so the apparent "weirdness" of putting `and` before `between` in terms of execution is not really a thing.

Comment: @allmhuran  _the "evaluation" in the documentation is really with respect to parsing, not execution_ , yes this is is the crucial point I realized thanks to comments.  That documentation should be emended

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert), [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) and [allmhuran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7165279/allmhuran) for the clarification.

The crucial point to understand is that : ***the "evaluation" in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is really with respect to parsing, not actual execution***.

Suppose having the following table

```
Test
[col1, col2, col3]
1      2     'a'
0      4     'e'
0      2     'f'
```

The following query is then executed against the above table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test 
WHERE col3 LIKE 'a%' AND col1*col1*col1<>0 AND col2/col1>0;
```

Now ***the Operator Precedence*** doesn't determine the evaluation order of conditions, but, as Martin Smith said in his comment, it ***is just about where the implied parentheses would go.***

In this case the two AND have the same precedence and the query is parsed in one of the two following ways:

```
(col3 LIKE 'a%' AND col1*col1*col1<>0) AND col2/col1>0  (1)
```

or

```
col3 LIKE 'a%' AND (col1*col1*col1<>0 AND col2/col1>0)  (2)
```

(*in my case* the first one (1)) and then the optimizer (always *in my case*!!) chooses to execute the division `col2/col1>0` first and a `division by zero` error is thrown.

**Keep in mind the *declarative* nature of SQL**:  you say ***what*** you want ***not how*** it's done:  this is left to the dbms engine which will performs optimizations, create the optimal query plan and execute it returning the desired result.

Comment: The SQL Server optimizer is actually a bit worse in this respect in the sense that even query stages are irrelevant for (intermediate) evaluation: it may choose to evaluate just about any subexpression "whenever", so that (notoriously) a `SELECT 1 / a FROM .. WHERE a <> 0` may fail with a division by zero because `1 / a` is evaluated before (or in parallel with) `a <> 0`, and this is not considered an error (by the optimizer authors, at least). Only an expression like `1 / NULLIF(a, 0)` would be safe, as the optimizer cannot get around doing the comparison with 0 first in this case.

Comment: You're mixing up short circuiting, order of precedence, and declarative languages. This answer to your own question is simply wrong. Order of precedence only relates to where the implicit brackets go, anything else (short circuiting, cached scalars, order of execution, parallelism, declarative languages, etc, etc) is completely independent. (Also, the declarative language aspect very rarely has any bearing on the evaluation of scalar expressions.)